# How can I add a bold text inside the mailTo tag in html?

Tags: html, text, encoding, mailto, bold

let body="Hi%0D%0AIssue%20%3A%0D%0Aemail ID%20%3A%0D%0A";
in mailTo tag ,I want to write the encoded text which must be bold .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible at all because mail body has inbuild CSS and and this would be a security issue according to RFC standards ( RFC 2368).